# LCD VGA Display goes blank on use of usb mouse on Pi 3

Tags: hdmi, display

I have an old VGA monitor (Xerox XM7-19w which has its prime resolution as 1440x900 (i.e. WXGA) at 60Hz. I've connected my recently purchased Pi 3 (and recently purchased sdcard with Rasbian on it) using a PiHut hdmi to vga converter without using the audio out as the monitor has no built in speakers and I only have usb speakers. Only my mouse & keyboard are connected by usb (directly to the Pi) and my internet is connected by ethernet cable.

Booting up is Ok (whether I have the monitor switched on before booting or after booting to Raspbian GUI). The monitor displays Ok but goes blank when I move the mouse. I can get the display on by powering it on and off but it happens again when I move the mouse. I've successfully installed Raspbian from the above mentioned sdcard and upgraded the software Ok, with lots of monitor switching off & on.

I've tried adding to the config.txt (just containing hdmi_force_hotplug=1) e.g. hdmi_ignore_edid=oxa5000080, hdi_drive=2, hdmi_group=2, hdmi_mode=47. But still no improvement.

Comment: How is it working with an other mouse (different product)? Same mouse on different USB port?

Comment: @Fabian No change with same mouse on different USB port.

Comment: No change with different mouse. I've tested the Pi with another VGA monitor and it's Ok with that. So problem is the monitor.

Comment: It sounds to me that the Keyboard, Mouse and monitor you have together are drawing too much current from the Pi. Would you be able to tell us the brand and models of the keyboard and mouse aswell as the rating of your Pi’s power supply?

Answer (score 0):

I've tested the Pi with another VGA monitor and it's Ok with that. So problem is the monitor.

Comment: If this is the solution to your question so please accept it with a click on the tick on its left side. Only accepting an answer will finish the question and it will not pop up again and again for years.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think mouse will do anything with display, both should be unrelated. Is the mouse a wireless mouse, have you tried with a different HDMI to VGA adapter. Mainly check with a secondary display. For example a TV.

I don't think if the mouse is wired, it can mess up hardware. But I guess if your raspberry pi is not having enough power, it can turn off.

Check if the red led light is on and steady